# How to connect and listen to external websocket url using C# and ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-core

I am trying to create a bot which that listen to an WebSocket URL with C# and ASP.Net Core 2.2.

But I’m new in WebSocket area.

I read Microsoft documentation about WebSocket and ClientWebSocket to solve my problem. but there are not help to me.

How my app can listen to an external WebSocket URL and react to incoming messages ?

I tried below code but get "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'WebSocket'." error.

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws.example.com"))
{
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Message received" + e.Data);
    ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    ws.Connect();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work? 
You need to be more specific in your question as this is not the place to outsource code writing for free to the internet

Comment: Are you trying to get streaming messages like xml data?

Comment: @jdweng no, like json data

Comment: @DenisSchaf I told which I am new in the websocket area and all of my code which I was trying were not helpful.

Comment: See code project.  The is full source code : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: @jdweng This is not helpful for my problem. Because I want to listen to WebSocket protocol, but in that url which you point to, explain on HTTP.

Comment: A Websocket is HTTP protocol.  A Web tool usually implies that you are going to display results in a browser.  If you do not need to display, using a Web tool is slower than http because you have to refresh the view.

Comment: `WebSocket` is an abstract class , you can use [ClientWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netcore-2.2)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it in the base case scenario.

```
 public class Listener
    {
        public void StopListening()
        {
            this.src.Cancel();
        }
        private Task listenTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource src=new CancellationTokenSource();
        public Task Listen(string url)
        {

           listenTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                        Console.WriteLine(data);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //treat exception
                }
            },src.Token);
        }
    }
```

However if you plan to create multiple `Listener` objects  ( in the context of a `HttpController` that on a route opens `sockets` ) then things change.